# Command Prompt becomes inactive after some time while running python progarm

Tags: python-3.x, command-prompt

I have a python program and I want to run that program all day. I am running this program from command prompt. After some time command prompt becomes inactive.  And when I use enter button it becomes active. Any resolution for this.
I use the following command:

```
python programName.py
```

My expectation is - Command prompt should not keep inactive.

Comment: That's how command prompts are designed - you can't start a new program until the previous one finishes.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux:

Use a 'fire & forget' method.

```bash
./my_script &
```

The `&` will let the script run in the background.
Or set the task as a cronjob.

Another option is to use `screen` or `tmux`, and then run the script.

When your OS is Windows:

Use the [Task Scheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10) to run the task, or create a Windows Service.
Or use a 3rd party tool, but i'm unaware of those.

Answer (score 0):

add a process like this

```
def inf_loop(arg1):
    while True:
        datetime.sleep(1)

p = Process(target=inf_loop, args=('',))
p.start()
p.join()
```